# Can't insert values into a transactional table in Apache HIVE

Tags: hive

I'm trying to insert values into a bucketed, transactional table both via Beeline and Apache HUE, but it receive an Error, saying that unlocking locks is not permited.

```
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;


USE classicmodels;

CREATE TABLE classicmodels.my_emp (ID INT, Name STRING, Salary INT)
CLUSTERED BY (ID) INTO 5 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');

INSERT INTO TABLE classicmodels.my_emp (id, name, salary)
VALUES (1, 'John', 10000),
       (2, 'Sara', 12000),
       (3, 'Adam', 8000);
```

[Error in beeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNW6g.png)
[Existing Locks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMPWz.png)

Error in HUE:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.LockException(Error communicating with the metastore) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQ...

Comment: Please can you paste the whole error so we can see the bit about unlocking locks?

Comment: The problem was related to metastore, for some reasons it didn't want to process locks. Since I used docker container to work with Hive, the replacement of metastore in docker-compose helped. I can't post the error message since its ~30 lines long.